# Checkbox Value not showing in Email

Tags: php, html, forms, checkbox

So I have created a simple form for registrations. Everything works perfectly except for the check boxes. They do not seem to show in the E-mail that is sent to the recipient.

Here is the HTML form section:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" name="projectType[]" value="Logo/Identity System" required/>Logo/Identity System<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" name="projectType[]" value="Poster" required/>Poster<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" name="projectType[]" value="Brochure" required/>Brochure<br />

<input type="checkbox" class="radio" name="projectType[]" value="Ad Campaign" required/>Ad Campaign<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" name="projectType[]" value="Website" required/>Website<br />
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" name="projectType[]" value="Other" required />Other<br />
```

Here is the PHP section:

```
<?php
$to = 'bolanosjd@gmail.com';
$projectType = $_POST['projectType'];
$body = "Project Type:$projectType\n"
if ($_POST['submit']) {
    if (mail ($to, $body)) {
        echo '<p>You have successfully registered for 2014 Designathon!</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

When the button submit is pressed all the information is sent but the "Project Type:" comes in empty with no value. How can I get it to show the values of the checkboxes selected? Don't mind the class "radio" They were previously radio buttons which worked fine but the client wanted multiple selections.

Comment: Sidenote: Missing `;` at `$body = "Project Type:$projectType\n"` and make sure your submit button is named `submit` but won't make it an answer, fearing it's a typo.

Comment: @Fred-ii- never fear to answer ;)

Comment: They usually open up "cans for worms" lol @meda

Comment: No i have that in the orignal php that was just a type-o when entering the code. the php works it's just that checkbox comes in empty. everything else shows up.

Comment: ^--« You see? @meda I knew it was a typo ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Omg you were so right , I understand why you reacted this way now lol

Comment: @meda It's always best to comment before jumping to conclusions. Least, in my experiences ;-)

Comment: You're going to get a **rude awakening** with your present form and any of the answers given below. Seeing that you're using checkboxes, all checkboxes will need to be checked before your form will execute, because you're using `required` for all of them. You may have originally had your checkbox options as radio buttons and made them as checkboxes. @WeebleWobb - This `class="radio"` was also a sign for me earlier. Therefore, you need to remove all your `required` or go about it in another way.

Comment: @Fred-ii- you really pay attention to details, I dont think OP intended to have them required as checkboxes are supposed to be optional. good catch!

Comment: Indeed I do. I started testing the OP's code and "I'm the one" who got the "rude awakening" @meda - Just *sharing the wealth* ;-) My guess is, the OP wants to use radio buttons, not checkboxes if only one is to be chosen, seeing the `"other"` option.

Comment: @WeebleWobb It's really hard to know exactly what you're looking to get as results. Seeing that you have checkboxes with required for all of them, yet your class shows as "radio". Is your form to allow people only ONE choice, or a mix of any? I was going to put in a "working" piece of code, but at this point I won't, seeing that I don't know exactly what you're looking to get. Plus, I noticed you haven't accepted any of the answers given so far.

Comment: @Fred-ii- actually no, becuase all the check boxes are in a group using the same name they do not need to be all checked to execute. I have tested it and it runs if only 1 is checked to all of them checked. No error what so ever. THe issue was that there was no value showing for the check boxes. No other error. But the issue has been solved. This registration form is not ment for anything grand but a simple event sign up. Thank you for the considereation

Comment: In my Firefox 27.0.1, it wouldn't let me go any further if only the one option was checked. Which browser are you using? @WeebleWobb - Some users with the same browser as I, may be faced with the same issue, best to look into that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to send to email an `array`, but `need a string`.
Simple change your code from :

```
$body = "Project Type:$projectType\n"
```

to:

```
$types = implode(', ', $projectType);
$body = "Project Type:$types\n";
```

Comment: [`not so fast`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22074584/checkbox-value-not-showing-in-email#comment33477398_22074584) LOL! @meda

Comment: This worked great but you forgot to put a "," betweent the "glue" and the array. But it worked out great. Also they way you wrote it I thought it replaced `$projectType = $_POST['projectType'];` but actually the implode goes below.Some trial and error but it worked out great. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

List the checkbox values using `implode()` like that:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {

  $to = 'bolanosjd@gmail.com';
  $projectType = $_POST['projectType'];
  $body = "Project Type: " . implode(", ", $projectType) ."\n";

    if (mail ($to, $body)) {
        echo '<p>You have successfully registered for 2014 Designathon!</p>';
    } else {
        echo '<p>Something went wrong, go back and try again!</p>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: good answer, I moved the variable inside of the condition to avoid undefined values

Comment: Thanks. sergio copied the `implode`

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_POST['projectType'] as $value){
  echo $value;
}
```

Comment: where exactly would this go? Within the 
    `if ($_POST['submit']) {
 if (mail ($to, $subject, $body, $from)) {
 }`

Answer (score -1):

You've set project type as an array ( the `[]` ). Remove the square brackets and it should work as expected. I'd have thought "Array" would be passed though.

`<input type="checkbox" class="radio" name="projectType" value="Logo/Identity System" required/>Logo/Identity System`

Or, see the example by keaner, which loops through all potential values (if more than one can be selected)

Comment: Actually you need the bracket

Comment: That's not related. Why would you want to remove the `[]`s? This won't work without them.

Comment: It is if the op meant to use `radio` rather than `checkbox` as the class implies. There was no mention of wanting more than one type to be in the email body